# Exception in thread "something thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. What can I do?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, out-of-memory

I have a following Error Message from my eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "th3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at Apeiron.FBM.Analysis.Clustering.Key.PatternClusterKey.Load(PatternClusterKey.java:260)
    at Apeiron.FBM.Analysis.UserBin.WaferUserDefineBin.CreatePatternClusterKey(WaferUserDefineBin.java:50)
    at Apeiron.FBM.Analysis.UserBin.UserDefineBin.Load(UserDefineBin.java:244)
    at Apeiron.FBM.Analysis.UserBin.WaferUserDefineBinDictionary.CreateUserDefineBin(WaferUserDefineBinDictionary.java:70)
    at Apeiron.FBM.Analysis.UserBin.UserDefineBinDictionary.Load(UserDefineBinDictionary.java:162)
    at Apeiron.MultiCore.OutputFileCreator.LoadDictionary(OutputFileCreator.java:357)
    at Apeiron.MultiCore.OutputFileCreator.run(OutputFileCreator.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Program of Apeiron is accomplished by four Threads & call a file that can be read with "org.w3c.dom.Document". That file becomes the object of WaferUserDefineBin.

So, I have done some experiments.
 The phenomena I figure out are following:
  1. I think it is not about heap size.
     Maximum memory of my eclipse is 256M but My program use just 40M ~ 50M.
     and I have tried to expanse heap size to 512M from eclipse.ini file.

1. It is problem of the file size that is changed WaferUserDefineBin.
    If I lessen size of the file, It doesn't happen Error.
2. It is problem of Multi-Threading.
    It does good operation in single-thread even if Size of the file is big.
3. Also, I use a Lock at region of reading the file but, Same Error occurs.

   I'm sorry for my poor English ability.
   Thanks a lot for your Help in advance.

Comment: Of course it's a heap-space problem - your first clue should be "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" at the top of the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase the memory (heap size), but for your program, not for Eclipse itself.

You can find these settings in the "Run Configurations". There is a tab "Arguments" with an area "VM arguments". Put your -Xm there.

Comment: I sincerely thank you Thilo. I solve my problem for your answer.    "In Run->Run Configuration find the Name of the class you have been running, select it, click the Arguments tab then add:

-Xms512M -Xmx1524M

to the VM Arguments section"   But, I don't know difference between eclipse.ini and "Run Configurations". Actually, I mainly use C#.